# Delphi canvas figures

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-units

i got some homework on Dephi (never used it before, only c++/java but in my universuty we've got delphi language subject). Well, i need to make form with moving figures, shown how they collides and stuff like. I started to make a uint like some abstarct class

```
unit MyFigure;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, Buttons, StdCtrls;

type
tPoint = record
 x,y: Double;
end;

oFigure = class
  c: TCanvas;
  pos: tPoint;
  vel: tPoint;
  r: Double;
  constructor create(coord, vect: tPoint; radius: Double);
  protected
    procedure move();
    procedure draw(); virtual;
  public
    function isIntersected(x:oFigure):boolean;
end;

implementation

  constructor oFigure.create(coord, vect: tPoint; radius: Double);
  begin
    pos.x:= coord.x;
    pos.y:= coord.y;
    vel.x:= vect.x;
    vel.y:= vect.y;
    r:=radius;
  end;

  procedure oShape.draw(); virtual;
  begin

  end;

  procedure oShape.move();
  begin
      pos.x:=  pos.x + vel.x;
      pos.y:=  pos.y + vel.y;
      oShape.draw();

  end;

  function isIntersected(o:oFigure):boolean;
  begin
     if ((oShape.pos.x - o.pos.x)*(oShape.pos.x - o.pos.x) +  (oShape.pos.y - o.pos.y)*(oShape.pos.y - o.pos.y)
          < (oShape.r + o.r)*(oShape.r + o.r)) then Result:=True;
  end;



end.
```

Then I created it's child. Well, here i need to call arc method from canvas to draw ball, but it don't see it and eve says `unable to invoke code completion`. Whats wrong?

```
unit Ball;

interface
uses
  MyFigure;   
type

oBall = class(oFigure);
    c: TCanvas;
    procedure draw(); override;
 end;

implementation
   procedure oBall.draw();
    begin
       c.Arc()//PROBLEM!
    end;

end.
```

Comment: You need to learn the basics first.

Comment: oh, well, i got not so much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code completion is not invoked because the unit **graphics** is not specified in the uses clause: Try with

```
unit Ball;

interface
uses
  Graphics, MyFigure;
```

By the way you don't seem to instanciate **c**. You'd need a constructor and a destructor for this. The usuall way would be to pass a TCanvas instance as parameter in the procedure draw(). In the unit **oFigure**, You define *TPoint* but TPoint is a native type of the RTL/VCL. You don't need to to define it. In **oFigure** you also set some methods as protected but paradoxycally the previous variables are public.

Comment: With such canvas object you can do just nothing.

Comment: Totally agree, Danil Gholtsman needs to pass an existing instance of a TCanvas in the Draw() Procedure. But basically as he is calling **c.Arc** without having instanciated **c** it was worth mentionning this.

Comment: I see what you mean, but you can't just instantiate `TCanvas` and start to draw *somewhere*. At least you need an object that will be able to respond to the `WM_PAINT` message and since OP uses `TObject` as a base class, it's impossible to do so. The `TGraphicControl` base class will be better for this.

Comment: The `TPoint` defined here isn't the same as the native type; the native type doesn't use `double` to represent the location. This would be a new type, `MyFigure.TPoint`. There are many other problems in the code, but this wouldn't be one of them.